# mysqli_fetch в echo выдает "Array"

Tags: php, mysql

Есть некоторый скрипт который отвечает за то, чтобы взять TEXT из столбика coord по запросу key. С помощью запроса SELECT я получаю эту строку. А вот чтобы вывести её в echo ничего не получается. Пробовал mysqli_fetch (array, assoc, row).

```
if (!empty($key)){
        $coord = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT coord FROM base WHERE _key = '".$key."'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($coord)){
            echo $row;
        }
    }
```

Когда это все дело открываю в бразузере вижу строку "Array" и больше ничего.

Comment: логично, fetch возвращает именно массив. посмотреть его содержимое можете каким нибудь var_dump и печатайте из него нужный элемент. Откройте доку на fetch и посмотрите примеры http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

Само собой. Используйте что-то в роде:

```
foreach($massiv as $value)
{
echo $value, «<br>»;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт? Что не так делает? `$massiv` нужно заменить на имя массива, если вы это не сделали.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае нужно сделать вот так:

```
if (!empty($key)){
        $coord = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT coord FROM base WHERE _key = '".$key."'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($coord)){
            echo $row['coord'].'`<br>`';
        }
    }
```